# Number of cycle-free sets of edges in complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The complete graph $K_n$ has edge set $E_n$ of size $\binom{n}{2}.$ My question: Is there a known formula for the number of subsets of $E_n$ which do not contain any cycles? For $n=3$ with $E_3$ of size $3,$ the only subset with a cycle is the entire $E_3$ so the count of cycle-free edge sets here is $2^3-1=7.$ I tried to work out by hand the case for $n=4$ and got 
$$ \binom{6}{0}+\binom{6}{1}+\binom{6}{2}+[\binom{6}{3}-4],$$
where the subtracted $4$ in the count for subsets of size $3$ is from removing the four sets of three edges forming a cycle. Since also as I convinced myself there are not any cycle-free subsets having $4,5,6$ edges, the above count should be complete.

I tried going beyond $4$ but even the $n=5$ case became hard to keep track of. So I'm wondering if this number is known, or if there is a summation, or generating function, etc. that counts this number.

Note that in the count, the empty set of edges is included, and that the edge sets counted do not have to be connected.

Comment: A cycle-free subset of $E_n$ has at most $n-1$ elements. The number of cycle-free subsets of size $n-1$ is $n^{n-2},$ i.e., the number of labelled trees on $n$ vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=5$ the count is
$$\binom{10}0+\binom{10}1+\binom{10}2+\left[\binom{10}3-\binom53\right]+5^3=291.$$
In general, the **number of forests of trees on $n$ labeled nodes** is given by OEIS sequence [A002858](https://oeis.org/A001858). The first few values are 1, 1, 2, 7, 38, 291, 2932, 36961, 561948, 10026505, 205608536, 4767440679, 123373203208, 3525630110107, 110284283006640, 3748357699560961, 137557910094840848, 5421179050350334929, 228359487335194570528, 10239206473040881277575, 486909744862576654283616; the OEIS gives [a table of values](https://oeis.org/A001858/b001858.txt) for $n\le100.$

**Update.** Here's how you can calculate the numbers recursively. Let $a(n)$ be the number of forests on $n$ labeled nodes, and let $b(n,k)$ be the number of forests on $n$ labeled nodes with exactly $k$ connected components, i.e., exactly $n-k$ edget. Then:
$$a(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nb(n,k)$$
and
$$b(n,k)=\frac1k\sum_{m=1}^{n-k+1}\binom nm b(m,1)b(n-m,k-1)$$
with boundary varues $b(n,1)=n^{n-2}$ ([Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula)) and $b(0,0)=1.$

**Update.** OEIS has a simple recurrence due to Alois P. Heinz: $a(0)=1$ and
$$a(n+1)=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj(j+1)^{j-1}a(n-j).$$
With nodes labeled $v_0,v_1,\cdots,v_n,$ the term $\binom nj(j+1)^{j-1}a(n-j)$ counts forests in which the tree containing $v_0$ has $j+1$ nodes.

Comment: Thanks, agrees with what I got in question (38) for $K_4,$ and I sure didn't have much luck by hand in counting the 291 cases for the $K_5$ graph.